# Symantec Endpoint Protection disk space

Tags: windows-server-2008, symantec

On a Windows SBS 2008 server we have Symantec Endpoint Protection Manager installed (version 12.1.671.4971). Also, the Symantec Endpoint Protection client is installed on the server (same version).

The server has a limited amount of diskspace, and they are starting to run out. I've run a scan with TreeSize to see what's taking up all the space and I've noticed this:

> C:\ProgramData\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint
>   Protection\12.1.671.4971.105\Data\Definitions\VirusDefs

This folder is taking up 6,2GB and it contains folders like "20130110.024", "20121217.003", etc. etc. There are about 16 of such folders in the VirusDefs folder, which is weird because I've set in the SEPM settings to only keep the last 3.

But, I've also found this folder:

> C:\ProgramData\Symantec\Definitions\SymcData\virusdefs32

This folders is about 1,2GB and contains three subfolders like "20130110.005". Since this folder only contains three folders it would seem the settings of SEPM are applied here.

We're getting to my question: Can I safely delete the old definitions folders from the VirusDefs folder? And where could I set the setting to only keep the latest three virus definitons, like in the virusdefs32 folder.

Thanks.

Comment: "Can I safely delete the old definitions folders" - Have you tried renaming/moving the folders and checking over the course of a few days whether anything breaks?

Comment: Was thinking about trying out something like that. Thanks. Just added a letter to the last three folder names and seeing what happens.

Comment: Renaming those folders makes the problem even worse. Symantec adds 3 new folders to replace the old ones so there is a setting somewhere that tells Symantec to keep 16 revisions but I have no idea where this is set.

Comment: A real Hydra, eh? ;) I hope you asked on the Symantec forum as well.

Comment: Yes, just posted it there. Hopefully we'll get a fix for this pretty soon.

Comment: @Matthias Hi. Have you found solution on how to modify number of revisions or delete folders safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Symantec forums:

```
Known issue; upgrade your SEPM to 12.1 RU2 (12.1.2015)

Rebooting the server may also help until upgrade.
```